# message.content.replace() not replacing the " .removedir" of the string

Tags: python, string, discord.py

I am making a command for a discord bot to delete a directory. However I am trying to get the path that the user passes and then replace the command with blank so only the path exists. This apparently does not work, and neither does it send an embed with the result for some reason.

Command code:

```
if message.content.startswith(".deletedir"):
        await message.delete()
        try:
            os.rmdir(message.content.replace(".deletedir ", ""))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Delete Directory", description="Failed to delete directory. Usage: ``.deletedir <FULL DIRECTORY PATH>``\nIf you want to delete files use the ``.delete`` command!", color=0x00ff00)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Delete Directory",description=f"Directory {message.content.replace('.deletedir ', '')} deleted.", color=0x00ff00)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I tried saving the replaces string into a variable and then pasing it into the os.rmdir(), I tried using .split(" ")[1] on the command too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is it ".deletedir " or is it ".removedir "?  Also, wouldn't those ```message.content.replace(".deletedir ", "")``` replace instances of ```.deletedir " with an empty string?

Comment: So what doesn't work? What happens, what doesn't happen? Have you tried printing out the path that would be deleted?

Comment: printing out results in: ".deletedir <Path here>"

Comment: Firstly, you need to make sure you have the *exact* path. Secondly, you need to have the correct permissions. Thirdly, that kind of script is dangerous as you could well delete something you didn't want to delete.

Comment: also it is .deletedir, my bad!

Comment: I do have the exact path, the problem is it doesn't remove the command part of the message, which results in unknown path.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor the command parsing a bit altogether:

```
if message.content.startswith("."):
    command, rest = message.content[1:].split(None, 1)
    if command == "deletedir":
        try:
            os.rmdir(rest)
        except Exception as e:
            ...
    elif command == "something-else":
        ...
```